# akka onComplete doesnt seem to work. java.lang.ClassCastException when trying to cast

Tags: scala, casting, akka, classcastexception

I currently try to ask an actor and do stuff afterwards "onComplete".

Here my example:

(this snippet is contained in a method)

```
(receivingActor ? message).mapTo[ReturnMessage].onComplete {
  case Success(rm) =>
    rm.getEitherObjectOrError() match {
      case Left(a) => return a
      case Right(e) =>
        sender ! ReturnMessage(None, Some(e))
        context.stop(self)
    }
  case Failure ... (doesnt matter)
}
```

When I try to cast my any object to the expected type...

```
any.asInstanceOf[ExpectedType]
```

... I receive the following exception:

```
 ERROR akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy - scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to ExpectedType
 java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to ExpectedType
```

Usually I`d expect any as an object of type "Any", so... What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you switch your `onComplete` to an `andThen` you can achieve the completion side effects you desire as well as retain the original return type of the `Future` returned from the `ask`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Future.onComplete` has a return type of `Unit`, basically it doesn't return anything.

Comment: but... as you can see there is a "return" inside my code snippet. This is part of a method. when I use the method it returns my object correctly, but afterwards I get the same exception again when I try to cast..

Comment: Your return is ignored. The definition of onComplete: `def onComplete[U](func: Try[T] => U): Unit`. So your function can return anything (`U`) the internal behavior of `Future` is to not care, ignore it and return `Unit`. Your `any` has type `Unit` and value `()`.